# Are there any online platforms like IQ Option to trade stocks online?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, online-trading

Are there any stock trading platform to buy stocks online like IQ Option?
IQ option allows to buy CFD's but as far as I know we buyer doesn't own shares.
I want to know whether there are any real platforms to deal with real stocks?

Comment: Fidelity, Schwab, TD Ameritrade, E*Trade, etc don't let you actually *buy* shares?

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Most(?) brokers these days also have an online presence. I think Googling for "online broker" already offers a lot of choices. Our company has been using  [Interactive Brokers](https://interactivebrokers.com) for 5 years now and I can recommend them; they accept personal accounts as well.